# Нужна помощь с полями для ввода текста

Tags: html

допустим у меня есть поле для ввода названия статьи и я хочу видеть количество символов которые я ввел. Что нужно сделать чтобы я видел количество введенных символов?

Comment: Можно сделать при помощи js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const div = document.querySelector('div');

input.addEventListener('input', ev => {
  div.textContent = ev.target.value.length;
});
```

```html
<input type='text'>
<div></div>
```